# li text automatically comes to center if the space is not enough

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul id="id_taxonomy_terms">
    <li>
    <label for="id_taxonomy_terms_0">
    <input id="id_taxonomy_terms_0" type="radio" value="1" name="taxonomy_terms">
    test1
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="id_taxonomy_terms_1">
    <input id="id_taxonomy_terms_1" type="radio" value="2" name="taxonomy_terms">
    test2test2test2
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="id_taxonomy_terms_2">
    <input id="id_taxonomy_terms_2" type="radio" value="3" name="taxonomy_terms">
    test3test3
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="id_taxonomy_terms_3">
    <input id="id_taxonomy_terms_3" type="radio" value="4" name="taxonomy_terms">
    Substance HolonymsSubstance HolonymsSubstance Holonyms
    </label>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the screenshot of the output:

[image: Output]

Here's the css I added:

```
#id_taxonomy_terms li{
    list-style-type: none;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Even if the list can't accomodate in the given div space I want it to float to the left and line break an continue with the text. How to do this?

Comment: Does `#id_taxonomy_terms` have a fixed width?

Comment: Yes, it is wrap under `<div class="col-md-3">`. I am using `bootstrap3`

Answer (score 1):

`float:left` is causing this to happen.  You don't even need it because you are setting a fixed value to `margin:right`.  Just remove it entirely.

```
#id_taxonomy_terms li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wYgMe/1)

Comment: @user2032220 Remove `float: left`

Answer (score 0):

With your current markup, lets assume `#id_taxonomy_terms` has a `width: 200px`, to align the `labels` properly to the right of the `inputs` do this:

**Method #1**

```
#id_taxonomy_terms {
    width: 200px;
}
#id_taxonomy_terms li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
#id_taxonomy_terms input {
    margin-left: -16px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YP7bC/

**Method #2** :

Requires that you change your markup a bit but the css uses `floats` instead of `negative margin`

```
#id_taxonomy_terms {
    width: 200px;
}
#id_taxonomy_terms li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    clear: both;
}
#id_taxonomy_terms input {
    float: left;
}
#id_taxonomy_terms label {
    float: left;
    width: 86%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xLWDs/

Comment: Hmm, since both methods didn't work then I'd suggest you should create a comprehensive jsfiddle demo so we can work off of that.

Comment: The second method was about to work but there's a gap between the radio button and text. Rest was fine.

Comment: You don't want a gap between the radio button and the text?

Comment: Add `margin: 4px 0 0 0` to the input as depicted here - http://jsfiddle.net/xLWDs/1/

Comment: This works but on the terms with more than one line the spacing is still there.

Comment: If you had a comprehensive demo or a url I can look at live i'll be able to help you further.